# Диалог при изменении версии

Tags: android, update, dialog

У меня есть приложение и по скольку оно имеет ряд недостатков и множество изменений при каждой новой версии, я хотел бы наглядно показывать, что в приложении изменилось.
Думаю в сторону диалогового окна с listview внутри, но вот как мне показывать этот диалог только после обновления приложения, а не каждый раз при открытии? И чтобы он показывался при каждом изменений версии приложения.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лично у себя в приложении я использую ооочень удобную библиотеку [WhatsNew](https://github.com/TonnyL/WhatsNew?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=7220#whatsnew). В ней можно сделать красивый список с изменениями и там есть еще дополнительные элементы для работы с интерфейсом, вот пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше еще проще, у вас есть кнопка для сворачивания диалога, вы ее нажимаете и дальше этот диалог будет показываться только при обновлении приложения. Вот часть описания к библиотеке:

> WhatsNew automatically displays a short description of the new
>   features when users update your app.

Но можно сделать и другим способом без использования сторонних библиотек. Например, берем `Dialog` с собственной разметкой которую украшаем и создаем по своему усмотрению. В этом диалоге мы тоже размещаем кнопку для сворачивания. При нажатии на кнопку мы в память устройства пишем переменную, что-то типа - `С фичами был ознакомлен` со значением true. И дальше уже проверяем при каждом старте приложения эту переменную и все. Лично я использовал библиотеку и было вполне удобно и просто.